# I want just users table rows in result

Tags: php, mysql, yii, criteria

this image is my MySQL tables.[image]

And these are my codes.

```
$buyuser = CHtml::encode($_POST['buyuser']);
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->distinct = FALSE;
            $criteria->with = array('addresses'=>array('alias'=>'adres', 'together'=>true),'addresses.city'=>array('alias'=>'city', 'together'=>true));
            $criteria->addCondition('t.name LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR t.name LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR t.lastname LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR t.lastname LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR adres.store LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR adres.store LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR city.name LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR city.name LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%"');
            $users = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

It works, But i want to also see duplicate records when city.name or lastname or store are one.
I need all addresses.

Comment: Just a side comment, next time you can paste sql code or an image from a tool like mysql workbench: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed base table in findAll and its my answer.

```
$buyuser = CHtml::encode($_POST['buyuser']);
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->distinct = FALSE;
        $criteria->with = array('user'=>array('together'=>true),'city'=>array('together'=>true));
        $criteria->addCondition('user.name LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR user.name LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR user.lastname LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR user.lastname LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR CONCAT(user.name," ",user.lastname) LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR CONCAT(user.name," ",user.lastname) LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR t.store LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR t.store LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%" OR city.name LIKE "'.$buyuser.'%" OR city.name LIKE "% '.$buyuser.'%"');
        $addresses = Addresses::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: You needed all addresses or all users with all addresses?